# Uploading image with Restkit - adding two rows to UITableView instead of one

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, image-uploading, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to post new managed object with image to the web database as below and everything works fine for me except the little weird bug. When the managed object is uploaded successfully,  2 rows are added instead of one to the UITableView. When I'm refreshing the UITableView the one of the previously added UITableViewCell is populating with uploaded image. When I rebuild the app everything works fine. Previously added managed object is displayed correctly without duplication.  Does anyone can take a look at my code and tell me what is the reason for that bug and how can I fix it? Let me know if you need more code.

```
 -(void)postRequest{
NSEntityDescription *watchEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Watches" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

Watches *watch = [[Watches alloc]initWithEntity:watchEntityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
watch.phonewatchno = @"124512";
watch.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-33.856870];
watch.longitude  = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:151.215279];


NSEntityDescription *wearersEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Wearers" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

Wearers *wearer = [[Wearers alloc]initWithEntity:wearersEntityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
wearer.name =_nameTextField.text,
wearer.watches =[NSSet setWithObject:watch];

RKEntityMapping *watchesMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Watches" inManagedObjectStore:[[EFDateModel sharedDataModel]objectStore]];
[watchesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                     @"id": @"watch_id",
                                                     @"latitude":@"latitude",
                                                     @"longitude":@"longitude",
                                                     @"phonewatchno":@"phonewatchno",

                                                     }
 ];

[watchesMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"wearer" connectedBy:@{
                                                                     @"wearer_id":@"wearer_id"
                                                                     }];
[watchesMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"watch_id"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescr = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:watchesMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/watches.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addResponseDescriptor:responseDescr];

RKEntityMapping *wearersMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Wearers" inManagedObjectStore:[[EFDateModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];

[wearersMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"id":@"wearer_id",
                                                     @"name":@"name",

                                                     }
 ];
wearersMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"wearer_id"];

[wearersMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"watch" toKeyPath:@"watches" withMapping:watchesMapping]];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:wearersMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/wearers.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[wearersMapping inverseMapping]  objectClass:[Wearers class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST ];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json"];




UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:_wearerImage.CGImage scale:0.4 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:wearer method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/wearers.json" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                name:@"wearer_photo"
                            fileName:@"photo.png"
                            mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];

NSManagedObjectContext *moc =[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore]mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *managedObjectOperation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Mapping result  = %@",mappingResult.array);
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"ReloadTable"
     object:self];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : \n %@",error.description);
}];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:managedObjectOperation];
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are calling this method you are calling `alloc]initWithEntity:... insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` twice and creating two new entity instances. You should probably be passing an entity instance to this method that it uses and not creating any new instances.

Also, it is inefficient to keep creating new descriptors and adding and removing them. And if you try to make 2 requests at the same time you will get an error. Configure the object manager once before you first use it and then just use it repeatedly without reconfiguring.